# How does strace connect to an already running process?

Tags: strace

I do know that `strace` uses `ptrace` to do the job,

but it needs to run the target process with `TRACE_ME` on,

which don't apply for the case of an already running process.

how does it work on an already running process?

Answer (score 56):

`strace -p <PID>`    ----> To attach a process to **strace**. "-p" option is for ***PID*** of the process.

`strace -e trace=read,write -p <PID>` --> By this you can also trace a process/program for an event, like read and write (in this example). So here it will print all such events that include read and write system calls by the process.

Other such examples

```
-e trace= network  (Trace all the network related system calls.)

-e trace=signal    (Trace all signal related system calls.)

-e trace=ipc       (Trace all IPC related system calls.)

-e trace=desc      (Trace all file descriptor related system calls.)

-e trace=memory    (Trace all memory mapping related system calls.)
```

and many more..

***trace*** is one of the many options you can use with **-e** option.

Press **Ctrl-C** to abbort the tracing by strace.

Check ***HELP*** section for brief summary on **strace** by typing `strace -h`
and **man** page for detailed info.

**NOTE**: A traced process runs slowly.

Comment: Surely the question is asking "how does the magic of 'attach' work?" not "what are the command switches to invoke the magic?"

Comment: @TomGoodfellow well there is no magic as such, only the commands with some other options which i have mentioned. Please read question and answer again. I don't know which part of it you didn't understand.

Comment: Here's that question: "I do know that strace uses ptrace to do the job, but it needs to run the target process with TRACE_ME on..." - it's a question about the implementation of ptrace() (and how strace uses it), not a question about using the strace command.

Comment: Title was "How does strace connect..." and I have answered based on that, about ptrace, and ptrace uses TRACE_ME i have no idea, even wiki, man page, or any other source didn't say anything related to those. So can't comment about the authenticity of what ptrace does internally.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is concerned about how strace uses ptrace to connect to already running processes; the asker is not concerned about how to use strace to connect to already running processes, but rather they want to know how does strace connect. Matthew's answer correctly answers this question.

Answer (score 38):

The details of `ptrace()` are OS-specific.

On Linux, a child may request to be traced by its parent with `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, ...)`; but, alternatively, a process may attach itself to another process with `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...)`.

See the [Linux `ptrace(2)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) (and, if you really want the fine details, the [`strace` source](http://strace.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=strace/strace;a=tree), and kernel source starting at [`kernel/ptrace.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0.4/kernel/ptrace.c)).

Comment: while the other answer is detailed and helpful for some searchers, it does not actually answer the original question, this one should be the accepted answer