# How to trace the write system call in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, system-calls, netfilter

I am trying to do this:
I am sending packet through iperf-an open source tool from one machine to another and I want to trace the write system or send call.
Please help me to do that,if someone can guide through Ftrace framework to trace system call that would be great otherwise by any other tracing tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I trace a system call in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840213/how-do-i-trace-a-system-call-in-linux) Voting to close this way because the other is more generic and has more upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

The hard part is to know exactly what to trace so you can see only the results that you want, but the tracing itself is very easy:

- First, your kernel must be configured with CONFIG_FTRACE=y
- Determine what event you want to trace

  cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/available_events
- Write the event that you have chosen into set_event

  echo sys_enter_write > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/set_event
- Determine what kind of trace you want to trace

  cat  /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/available_tracers
- Write the kind of trace that you want in current_tracer file

  echo function_graph > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/current_tracer
- Enable tracing:

  echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on
- Now you can run the "iperf -c... " as you wish, and disable tracing when it is done.

  echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on

To see the results:

vi /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace

Comment: i am getting the following error echo sys_enter_write > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/current_tracer -bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument [root@server tracing]# echo sys_enter_write > current_tracer -bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument

Comment: Are you running as root?

Comment: can you please send me a test mail on gunjanmehta08@gmail.com

Comment: Please see this video [Video demo](http://www.screenr.com/PzNN) i tried this on ubuntu and redhat, both worked. Maybe you could try to mount the debugfs on another directory using: mkdir /debug <enter> mount -t debugfs debugfs /debug <enter> cd /debug/tracing and execute the echo commands inside like I did on the video.

Comment: I managed to get the Invalid argument. I will update my answer in order to better explain how to trace events. My answer as it is now induced you to get this error.

Comment: Doing `echo function_graph > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/current_tracer` makes it trace all functions, and generates massive output, you likely want `nop` instead here. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889563/how-to-trace-the-write-system-call-in-the-linux-kernel/52776478#52776478

Answer (score 1):

**`strace`**

If you are going to just trace one process, why not just use `strace`? It can even connect to running processes: [How does strace connect to an already running process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482076/how-does-strace-connect-to-an-already-running-process)

**For ftrace, use `echo none > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/current_tracer` to trace just the system calls**

As of Linux 4.15 at least, if you use `function_graph` instead, then it shows a ton of functions in addition to the system call.

You could work around that with filtering, but it is simpler to just use `nop`: [How to trace just system call events with ftrace without showing any other functions in the Linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764544/how-to-trace-just-system-call-events-with-ftrace-without-showing-any-other-funct/52765387#52765387)

Run with `sudo`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eux

d=debug/tracing

mkdir -p debug
if ! mountpoint -q debug; then
  mount -t debugfs nodev debug
fi

# Stop tracing.
echo 0 > "${d}/tracing_on"

# Clear previous traces.
echo > "${d}/trace"

# Find the tracer name.
cat "${d}/available_tracers"

# Disable tracing functions, show only system call events.
echo nop > "${d}/current_tracer"

# Find the event name with.
grep write "${d}/available_events"

# Enable tracing write.
# Both statements below seem to do the exact same thing,
# just with different interfaces.
# https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/trace/events.html
echo sys_enter_write > "${d}/set_event"
# echo 1 > "${d}/events/syscalls/sys_enter_write/enable"

# Start tracing.
echo 1 > "${d}/tracing_on"

# Generate two write calls by two different processes.
rm -rf /tmp/a /tmp/b
printf a > /tmp/a
printf b > /tmp/b

# View the trace.
cat "${d}/trace"

# Stop tracing.
echo 0 > "${d}/tracing_on"

umount debug
```

and a sample output:

```
# tracer: nop
#
#                              _-----=> irqs-off
#                             / _----=> need-resched
#                            | / _---=> hardirq/softirq
#                            || / _--=> preempt-depth
#                            ||| /     delay
#           TASK-PID   CPU#  ||||    TIMESTAMP  FUNCTION
#              | |       |   ||||       |         |
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.454767: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 5558769acc00, count: 2)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.454777: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 555877f6a968, count: 2)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.454785: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 555877f6a968, count: 4)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.454793: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 555877f6a968, count: 7)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.454801: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 555877f6a968, count: 7)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.454807: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 7ffc5f3f2be7, count: 1)
 gnome-terminal--3419  [005] .... 11152.454833: sys_write(fd: 4, buf: 7ffe4f3a61c0, count: 8)
 gnome-terminal--3419  [005] .... 11152.454862: sys_write(fd: 4, buf: 7ffe4f3a61c0, count: 8)
 gnome-terminal--3419  [005] .... 11152.454887: sys_write(fd: 4, buf: 7ffe4f3a61c0, count: 8)
 gnome-terminal--3419  [005] .... 11152.454894: sys_write(fd: 4, buf: 7ffe4f3a61c0, count: 8)
           gmain-3193  [002] .... 11152.456141: sys_write(fd: 4, buf: 7fbfe5a93c40, count: 8)
           gmain-3193  [002] .... 11152.456168: sys_write(fd: 4, buf: 7fbfe5a92bd0, count: 8)
           gmain-3193  [002] .... 11152.456172: sys_write(fd: 4, buf: 7fbfe5a93c40, count: 8)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.456534: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 5558769acbd8, count: 2)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.456547: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 555877f6a968, count: 6)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.456555: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 555877f6a968, count: 2)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.456561: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 7ffc5f3f2be7, count: 1)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.456578: sys_write(fd: 1, buf: 555877f6af00, count: 1)
 gnome-terminal--3419  [005] .... 11152.456651: sys_write(fd: 4, buf: 7ffe4f3a61c0, count: 8)
 gnome-terminal--3419  [005] .... 11152.456660: sys_write(fd: 4, buf: 7ffe4f3a61c0, count: 8)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.456674: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 5558769acbd8, count: 2)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.456683: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 555877f6a968, count: 6)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.456690: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 555877f6a968, count: 2)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.456694: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 7ffc5f3f2be7, count: 1)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.456703: sys_write(fd: 1, buf: 555877f6af00, count: 1)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.456738: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 5558769acb88, count: 2)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.456745: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 555877f6a968, count: 3)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.456750: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 555877f6a968, count: 14)
            a.sh-18135 [004] .... 11152.456756: sys_write(fd: 2, buf: 7ffc5f3f2be7, count: 1)
 gnome-terminal--3419  [005] .... 11152.456816: sys_write(fd: 4, buf: 7ffe4f3a61c0, count: 8)
 gnome-terminal--3419  [005] .... 11152.456845: sys_write(fd: 4, buf: 7ffe4f3a61c0, count: 8)
```

As you can see, `write` is a very common system call, so it is difficult to isolate our two write calls. Things would be easier to see with a less common call, e.g. `mkdir`: [How do I trace a system call in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840213/how-do-i-trace-a-system-call-in-linux/51856306#51856306)

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, Linux kernel 4.15.

Comment: Is there a way to change the syscall trace output format to ftrace. eg in case of sys_enter_write one of output is filename: 5af693f224 as corresponding format is filename: 0x%08lx. Is it somehow possible to change format to get this as a string. Would be good if such a change only effects specified system call trace and not others. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55443204/change-format-of-syscall-event-trace-output-to-ftrace

Comment: sorry @rawatm but I don't know the answer :-) Do try to grep the kernel source a bit as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To get call graph of write syscall, you can:

```
sudo trace-cmd record -p function_graph -g vfs_write your-prog
```

your-prog can be simple write program like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
int main()
{
        int fd = open("a.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
        write(fd, "abcdefg", 6);
        close(fd);
}
```

Then `trace-cmd report | grep -v trace-cmd | less`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from ftrace, you can also use perf like:

```
sudo perf record --call-graph fp ./fio --filename=aa --size=4G --direct=0 --rw=write --bs=1M  --iodepth=512 --numjobs=1 --name=job_name
```

Then:

```
sudo perf report --call-graph
```

and expand vfs_write:

```
  Children      Self  Command  Shared Object       Symbol                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
+   80.17%     0.00%  fio      [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ◆
+   80.15%     0.02%  fio      [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] do_syscall_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ▒
+   78.57%     0.07%  fio      libpthread-2.31.so  [.] __libc_pwrite64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
-   78.49%     0.04%  fio      [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] vfs_write                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ▒
   - 78.46% vfs_write                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
      - 78.40% new_sync_write                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ▒
         - 78.37% ext4_file_write_iter                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
            - 78.33% ext4_buffered_write_iter                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ▒
               - 77.73% generic_perform_write                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ▒
                  - 50.15% ext4_da_write_begin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ▒
                     - 38.72% grab_cache_page_write_begin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ▒
                        - 38.61% pagecache_get_page                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ▒
                           - 23.52% __page_cache_alloc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
                              - 23.16% alloc_pages                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ▒
                                 - 22.63% __alloc_pages                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ▒
                                    - 22.00% get_page_from_freelist                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ▒
                                       - 18.16% prep_new_page                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ▒
                                            17.84% clear_page_rep                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ▒
                                         1.80% rmqueue                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
                                         1.28% node_dirty_ok                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ▒
                           - 12.84% add_to_page_cache_lru                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ▒
                              - 9.77% __add_to_page_cache_locked                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ▒
                                 - 1.89% __mem_cgroup_charge                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ▒
                                      1.01% charge_memcg                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ▒
                                      0.77% get_mem_cgroup_from_mm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ▒
                                 - 1.09% xa_get_order                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
                                    - 0.89% xas_load                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ▒
                                         0.53% xas_descend                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ▒
                              - 2.69% lru_cache_add                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ▒
                                 - 2.37% __pagevec_lru_add                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ▒
                                      2.01% __lock_text_start                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ▒
                           - 1.21% xas_load                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ▒
                                0.66% xas_descend                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ▒
                     - 10.38% ext4_block_write_begin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ▒
                        - 7.01% create_empty_buffers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ▒
                           - 5.98% alloc_page_buffers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
                              - 5.59% alloc_buffer_head                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ▒
                                 - 4.24% kmem_cache_alloc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ▒
                                    - 1.03% ___slab_alloc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ▒
                                       - new_slab                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ▒
                                          - 0.87% allocate_slab                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ▒
                                             - 0.57% alloc_pages                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ▒
                                                - 0.55% __alloc_pages                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
                                                     get_page_from_freelist                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ▒
                                      0.84% get_obj_cgroup_from_current                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ▒
                                   0.53% memset                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ▒
                        - 2.42% ext4_da_get_block_prep                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
                           - 1.26% ext4_da_map_blocks.constprop.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ▒
                                0.53% ext4_es_lookup_extent                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ▒
                  - 16.27% copy_page_from_iter_atomic                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
                       copy_user_generic_string                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ▒
                  - 8.74% ext4_da_write_end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ▒
                     - 8.23% generic_write_end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ▒
                        - 7.83% block_write_end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ▒
                           - __block_commit_write.isra.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ▒
                              - 6.89% mark_buffer_dirty                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ▒
                                 - 5.66% __set_page_dirty                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ▒
                                      5.54% __lock_text_start                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ▒
                    1.35% __get_user_nocheck_1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ▒
+   78.48%     0.00%  fio      [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] __x64_sys_pwrite64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ▒
+   78.48%     0.00%  fio      [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] ksys_pwrite64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ▒
+   78.40%     0.02%  fio      [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] new_sync_write                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
+   78.37%     0.02%  fio      [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] ext4_file_write_iter                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ▒
+   78.33%     0.00%  fio      [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] ext4_buffered_write_iter                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ▒
+   77.73%     0.27%  fio      [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] generic_perform_write                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ▒
+   50.28%     0.45%  fio      [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] ext4_da_write_begin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ▒
+   38.76%     0.07%  fio      [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] grab_cache_page_write_begin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ▒
+   38.74%     0.91%  fio      [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] pagecache_get_page                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ▒
+   25.19%     0.66%  fio      [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] __alloc_pages                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ▒
+   24.44%     0.64%  fio      [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] get_page_from_freelist
```