# How to trace just system call events with ftrace without showing any other functions in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, ftrace

For example, to monitor all `mkdir` calls made, the best I could come up with was:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eux

d=debug/tracing

mkdir -p debug
if ! mountpoint -q debug; then
  mount -t debugfs nodev debug
fi

# Stop tracing.
echo 0 > "${d}/tracing_on"

# Clear previous traces.
echo > "${d}/trace"

# Enable tracing mkdir
echo sys_enter_mkdir > "${d}/set_event"

# Set tracer type.
echo function > "${d}/current_tracer"

# Filter only sys_mkdir as a workaround.
echo SyS_mkdir > "${d}/set_ftrace_filter"

# Start tracing.
echo 1 > "${d}/tracing_on"

# Generate two mkdir calls.
rm -rf /tmp/a
rm -rf /tmp/b
mkdir /tmp/a
mkdir /tmp/b

# View the trace.
cat "${d}/trace"

# Stop tracing.
echo 0 > "${d}/tracing_on"

umount debug
```

And then after running with `sudo` it gives:

```
# tracer: function
#
# entries-in-buffer/entries-written: 4/4   #P:16
#
#                              _-----=> irqs-off
#                             / _----=> need-resched
#                            | / _---=> hardirq/softirq
#                            || / _--=> preempt-depth
#                            ||| /     delay
#           TASK-PID   CPU#  ||||    TIMESTAMP  FUNCTION
#              | |       |   ||||       |         |
           mkdir-31254 [015] .... 2010985.576760: sys_mkdir(pathname: 7ffc54b32c77, mode: 1ff)
           mkdir-31254 [015] .... 2010985.576763: SyS_mkdir <-tracesys_phase2
           mkdir-31255 [007] .... 2010985.578363: sys_mkdir(pathname: 7fff02d90c77, mode: 1ff)
           mkdir-31255 [007] .... 2010985.578365: SyS_mkdir <-tracesys_phase2
```

My problem with this is that it output two lines for each syscall:

- `sys_mkdir` which is the event that I want
- `SyS_mkdir` which is the filtered function workaround, which I don't want to see

If I instead try to do:

```
echo > "${d}/set_ftrace_filter"
```

or don't touch that file at at all, then it shows a ton of functions and makes it hard to fint the syscall at all.

If there a nicer way to disable regular functions, and keep just syscall events?

I could use just `SyS_mkdir` and disable the syscall event I guess, but it feels cleaner if I could use the more specific event? Also:

- the event shows arguments, which is nicer.
- syscall function names change across kernel versions. E.g., it is already `__x64_sys_mkdir` instead of `SyS_mkdir` on Linux v4.18.

Related:

- [How to trace the write system call in the Linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889563/how-to-trace-the-write-system-call-in-the-linux-kernel)

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, Linux kernel 4.15.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use the syscall tracing events directly?
i.e. `echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_mkdir/enable`.

Comment: @sruffell I can use that, but from my experiments I thought it was equivalent to the `echo sys_enter_mkdir > "${d}/set_event"` line I currently have.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, but then you don't need to set the function tracer, and can keep the `nop` tracer, so you don't need to set any filters.

Comment: @sruffell OK, I'll give it a try later on. Feel free to answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Use the `nop` tracer**

As [proposed by sruffell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764544/how-to-trace-just-system-call-events-with-ftrace-without-showing-any-other-funct/52765387#comment92455912_52764544), all we have to do is to use the `nop` tracer instead of `function`, and that will disable the function traces, but not the events.

Run with `sudo`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eux

d=debug/tracing

mkdir -p debug
if ! mountpoint -q debug; then
  mount -t debugfs nodev debug
fi

# Stop tracing.
echo 0 > "${d}/tracing_on"

# Clear previous traces.
echo > "${d}/trace"

# Find the tracer name.
cat "${d}/available_tracers"

# Disable tracing functions, show only system call events.
echo nop > "${d}/current_tracer"

# Find the event name with.
grep mkdir "${d}/available_events"

# Enable tracing mkdir.
# Both statements below seem to do the exact same thing,
# just with different interfaces.
# https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/trace/events.html
echo sys_enter_mkdir > "${d}/set_event"
# echo 1 > "${d}/events/syscalls/sys_enter_mkdir/enable"

# Start tracing.
echo 1 > "${d}/tracing_on"

# Generate two mkdir calls by two different processes.
rm -rf /tmp/a /tmp/b
mkdir /tmp/a
mkdir /tmp/b

# View the trace.
cat "${d}/trace"

# Stop tracing.
echo 0 > "${d}/tracing_on"

umount debug
```

This gives the desired output:

```
   mkdir-26064 [007] .... 2014370.909743: sys_mkdir(pathname: 7fffbd461c77, mode: 1ff)
   mkdir-26065 [014] .... 2014370.911615: sys_mkdir(pathname: 7ffea53bac77, mode: 1ff)
```

**Alternative not best solution**

This also works, but definitely less nice, replace:

```
echo SyS_mkdir > "${d}/set_ftrace_filter"
```

with:

```
echo '*' > "${d}/set_ftrace_notrace"
```

This turns off all functions as mentioned in the docs: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/trace/ftrace.html#the-file-system

> set_ftrace_notrace:
>
> This has an effect opposite to that of set_ftrace_filter. Any function that is added here will not be traced. If a function exists in both set_ftrace_filter and set_ftrace_notrace, the function will *not* be traced.

Answer (score 4):

In addition, it's worth mention another concise way to gain such info. One can do something like:

```
stap -e 'probe syscall.mkdir { printf("%s[%d] -> %s(%s)\n", execname(), pid(), name, argstr) }'
```

*The output*:

```
systemd-journal[318] -> mkdir("/var/log/journal/c8d2562a041649cdbfd1ac5e24dbe0db", 0755)
systemd-journal[318] -> mkdir("/var/log/journal/c8d2562a041649cdbfd1ac5e24dbe0db", 0755)
mkdir[4870] -> mkdir("wtf", 0777)
...
```

Another way:

```
stap -e 'probe kernel.function("sys_mkdir") { printf("%s[%d] (%s)\n", execname(), pid(), $$parms) }'
```

*The output*:

```
systemd-journal[318] (pathname=0x55b74f7ab8b0 mode=0x1ed)
systemd-journal[318] (pathname=0x55b74f7ab8b0 mode=0x1ed)
mkdir[8532] (pathname=0x7ffcf30af761 mode=0x1ff)
...
```

You can customize the output as you like.

P.S. Systemtap is based on [kprobes](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt). [Architecture doc](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/archpaper.pdf) will help to understand its internals.

[More about the **SystemTap**](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html-single/systemtap_beginners_guide/index).

Comment: It would also be good to say what is the underlying kernel interface used by SystemTap. ftrace, or something else?

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 Edited