# Change format of syscall event trace output to ftrace

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, system-calls, ftrace, tracepoint

I enabled ftrace event tracing for `sys_enter_openat` syscall. The respective output format given at `events/syscalls/sys_enter_openat/format` is

```
print fmt: "dfd: 0x%08lx, filename: 0x%08lx, flags: 0x%08lx, mode: 0x%08lx", ((unsigned long)(REC->dfd)), ((unsigned long)(REC->filename)), ((unsigned long)(REC->flags)), ((unsigned long)(REC->mode))
```

As expected a sample output line to ftrace is something like

```
msm_irqbalance-1338  [000] ...1 211710.033931: sys_openat(dfd: ffffff9c, filename: 5af693f224, flags: 2, mode: 0)
```

Is there a way to change output format such that `filename: 5af693f224` can be shown as `filename: <string>` instead of address?
I guess this would have been possible using `systemtap` or `krpobe` but my setup does not allow its use as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You can define kprobe events with your own format:

```
cd /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
echo 'p:open do_sys_open file=+0(%si):string' > kprobe_events
echo 1 > events/kprobes/open/enable
cat trace_pipe
```

which outputs:

```
cat-123 [001] .... 123.123: open: (do_sys_open+0x0/0x80) file="/etc/fstab"
cat-123 [001] .... 123.124: open: (do_sys_open+0x0/0x80) file="/dev/zero"
```

For details, see: https://events19.linuxfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/oss-eu-2018-fun-with-dynamic-trace-events_steven-rostedt.pdf